# Конфигурация Protractor, для игнора консольних ошибок в браузере

Tags: node.js, тестирование, protractor

В браузере ангулар выдает ошибки, которые, по сути, на работу не влияют, но как их исправить я пока не знаю. Проблема в том, что после появления ошибки в консоли, тест падает с сообщением об этой ошибке.

До конца не уверен, но это, кажется, не дефолтное поведение протрактора, - он, вроде бы, не должен учитывать консоль без дополнительных настроек.

Далее, я попробовал поставить к протрактору плагин `protractor-console-plugin`, который должен определять реакцию на события в консоли браузера, сконфигурировав его следующим образом:

```
plugins: [{
      package: 'protractor-console-plugin',
      //pakage: '/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor-console-plugin',
      failOnWarning: false,
      failOnError: false,
      logWarnings: false
}]
```

Но нужного результата не получил: тест и дальше падал после ошибки в консоли браузера.

Я так понял, в теперешней версии протрактора есть уже вмонтированные из коробки механизмы для этой опции, и они по-умолчанию настроены так, чтобы смотреть за консолью.

Подскажите, как отключить эту штуку? Или, как вариант, предложите какой-нибудь другой тестовый фреймворк. Но предпочтительней протрактор так как он будет ближе к ангулару.

Код конфига:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        //'browserName': 'firefox'
        'browserName': 'chrome'

    },

    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['spec/avtorization_test.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    plugins: [{
        package: 'protractor-console-plugin',
        //pakage: '/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor-console-plugin',
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: false,
        logWarnings: false
    }]
};
```

Код теста:

```
var
    testingAdress = 'http://localhost:1340',

describe('admin avtorization test', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        // should be called before each it block
    });

    it('should avtorizate as admin', function(){

        browser.get(testingAdress);

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('localhost:1340'+'/#!/');

        //element(by.linkText('Sign Up')).click();

        //expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(testingAdress + '/#!/signup');

        //element(by.id('myLink').click());
        //expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://myUrl.com");
    });

});
```